# How do I make a sheet filter only show checkmarked rows with multiple variables in G-Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet in google sheets that has a lot of checkmarks:

[image]

I want to create another checkbox filtering system, either at the top, if possible, or on another tab if not. I've tried putting the filter at the top, but as I'm sure you know, it overwrites the data, so no bueno. I also tried this:

[image: 0]

with this code:

```
=FILTER(Movies!A3:P1000,(IF(F2=0,Movies!F4:F1002=0,Movies!F4:F1002=1)))
```

Which doesn't seem to be doing what I want either? It's showing a random selection, it seems, rather than only the data with the F column being true.

Ideally, you click the checkmarks of the data you want to see, so, if you click the check under Andrew, Addison and Richie, it would only show the rows that had only Andrew, Richie, and Addison's checkmarks. I am fine with making the checkmarks a 0,1,2 list if needed. (Because checkmarks I think are only binary, unless they have an option somewhere to have a third option that I'm unaware of, and marking some data to not be seen if it doesn't have a checkmark would likely require a third option.)

[this is](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ANU957-FyVowXXcO2Us_2rhK-JmMI-1m8MluIxfgCsk/edit?usp=sharing) what I've got

Comment: Got it, I made a copy and made it editable.

Comment: can you provide an example of desired output? (it's not clear from your question)